# How to change all records from column if they have one index oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very interesting situation,
Lets say i have 3 postoffices
2 of them have type 'ТПС' and 1 'ПВПЗ'
my task is to put address of 'ТПС' to 'ПВПЗ' if they have same index.

here is my script

```
SELECT
PARENTPOSTDISTRICT.POSTCODE,
CASE WHEN ??? THEN ??? END address,
PARENTTYPE.ACRONYM_UA

FROM ADDR_POSTOFFICE PARENT
INNER JOIN ADDR_POSTOFFICETYPE PARENTTYPE
ON PARENT.POSTOFFICETYPE_ID = PARENTTYPE.ID AND PARENTTYPE.ACRONYM_UA IN ( 'ПВПЗ','ТПС')
INNER JOIN ADDR_POSTDISTRICT PAREntPOSTDIStRICT ON PARENT.ID = PAREntPOSTDIStRICT.POSTOFFICE_ID

WHERE PARENT.DATESTOP >= SYSDATE
AND PARENTPOSTDISTRICT.POSTCODE = '20234';
```

ADDR_POSTOFFICE - table with postoffices.
ADDR_POSTOFFICETYPE - table with postoffices types.
ADDR_POSTDISTRICT - lets say, it is table with postoffices indexes.
last condition, **POSTCODE = INDEX** (PARENTPOSTDISTRICT.POSTCODE = '20234')

any solutions?
if you need more information, just ask, i understand that it is tricky.

by the other example i have 3 colors with 3 numbers and same indexes

```
black, test1, 1
yellow, test2, 1
red, test3, 1
```

i need result to be

```
black, test1, 1
yellow, test1, 1
red, test3, 1
```

and exactly value there is not just string, it is record from row.

Comment: Unclear. Show DDL for tables (skip fields unnesessary for the task), some example data and desured result for this data. Or create a fiddle.

Comment: An index is an object in Oracle that (generally) improves performance when processing data.  I might think that your use of "index" refers to a column, but I see no such column in your sample query.  That makes your question really hard to understand.

Comment: I think you need `case when` and some analytic function (or subquery), probably like in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=646f38fe18afbb2080aa5b9f85978f66), but your question is not clear, please create fiddle if possible and explain why you took `test1` and not `test3`.